# SSRS User Select Excel File for Data Upload

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I have a requirement for a report where as part of selecting the parameters / filters, the user also selects an excel file to be upload. The data in the excel is then utilised as part of the query.

My question is, is this possible and how do you setup the selection paremeter to select the file?
Thanks in advance.

I searched and investigated various options, however no solution was found

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING:** This answer has lots of things that you should avoid for security, do this at your own risk!

To get a list of files, you can execute a command using xp_cmdshell, you'll need to allow this on the server as it's switched off by default. That aside, you can do something as simple as this.

```
DECLARE @filespec varchar(1000) = '\\myServer\MyFolder\UploadsToSQL\MyFiles\*.xlsx'
DECLARE @cmd varchar(1000) = 'dir ' + @filespec + ' /b'

exec xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

If you use this as a dataset query it will return a list of matching files, you can use this to populate your parameter drop down.

Once one of the files is selected and assuming the parameter is called `@file` then you can do the following to read the data in

Note: I have setup a login (AceDriverLogin) with all the required access in order for this to work.

```
DECLARE @file varchar(1000) = '\\myServer\MyFolder\UploadsToSQL\MyFiles\MyTestFile.xlsx'

DECLARE @XLSelect varchar(2000)
SET @XLSelect =
        'SELECT * 
         FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Excel 12.0;Database=' + @file + ';HDR=YES'',''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'') '

        exec (@XLSelect) as login = 'AceDriverLogin'
```

This will return the contents of "Sheet1"

If you need to do more work with the results, then you'll need to create a temp table to insert the data into and then you can do what you like with the temp table afterwards.

Something like this

```
DECLARE @file varchar(1000) = '\\myServer\MyFolder\UploadsToSQL\MyFiles\MyTestFile.xlsx'

CREATE TABLE #xlData ([FirstColumn] varchar(100), [SecondColumn] varchar(100), [ThirdColumn] varchar(100))

DECLARE @XLSelect varchar(2000)
SET @XLSelect =
        'INSERT INTO #xlData ([FirstColumn], [SecondColumn], [ThirdColumn]) ' +
        'SELECT [FirstColumn], [SecondColumn], [ThirdColumn]
         FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Excel 12.0;Database=' + @file + ';HDR=YES'',''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'') '

        exec (@XLSelect) as login = 'AceDriverLogin'

SELECT * FROM #xlData
```